# DecimalField without defining precision and scale

Tags: django, django-models

How to not specify `DecimalField` with `precision` and `scale`? In my `postgres` database i have columns either as `numeric` or `numeric(precision, scale)`. For columns defined as `numeric(precision, scale)` i reflected that in django using like : `models.DecimalField(max_digits=X, decimal_places=Y)` but how to define for `numeric`?

Comment: Would `float` fits in your situation?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu hmm.. I need to do what i wrote in main post